# Chatbox with new messages showing at the bottom and pushing old messages up

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am kinda stuck building the chat container of a chat gpt-like UI. The tricky part is that I want the messages to start from the bottom with new messages pushing the old ones further to the top. The page looks like this:

title / header
some text
| chat area, stretching the entire available height
|
|
|
| first message
| second message
| third message
input field
some other text and buttons

The page is always 100% height and has no scroll bar. Only the chat are should show a scroll bar when needed. The page is currently wrapped in a flex container with `flex-direction: column`.

**Approach I**

The closes I've been to having the chat area work as expected is by having two nested divs.

```css
#outer {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 1px;
  solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 16px;
  height: 50vmin;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#inner {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <messageOne />
    <messageTwo />
    <messageThree />
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue I am encountering with this approach is that no matter what I do the scroll bar is always present. It looks like one of the containers is a couple pixels higher than the other and thus the scroll bar is always visible.

**Approach II**

With this approach when the chat area gets filled with messages they start overflowing the container and horizontal scrollbar appears. I found no way of keeping the container from overflowing.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <messageOne />
  <messageTwo />
  <messageThree />
</div>
```

**PS:** I found that just having `display: block` on the container almost works as expected. The only thing missing in this case is making the messages start from bottom up. Experimented with absolute position and a lot of other stuff but couldn't quite get it to work.

Comment: We need some working example code in order to fully understand what you've done and how to go about fixing it. Try reproducing the problem in a CodePen example and share the result in your question—that will make it much easier for us to see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding overflow-y:scroll to #inner container in your first approach and remove overflow auto from #outer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That works in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Angel-Bozhkov/pen/WNPrZKy). I have tried that, but in my project I get the same issue as **Approach I**. The inner container always has scroll bar displayed. It seems that the container is a couple pixels shorter than the height of the content. Removing `font-size: 1.6rem` coming from the body fixes is, but messes up the styles. I will have to find a clean solution to that.
Thanks, will accept your answer.

Comment: Increasing the `line-height` on the message a bit solved that.. Cheers